# Cannot login in to the page using 3 tier architecture in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a project in asp.net c# using vs 2008.I wish to do my project in 3 tier architecture.I can insert values in to the table using 3tier.But cannot login into the page only signing up is possible.On running it shows the error as "Procedure or function 'login' expects parameter '@iusername', which was not supplied. "

My code is given below

Presentation layer

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

   String xusername = uname.Text;

    String xpwd = pwd.Text;

    try
    {
        bool match = oBAL.checking(xusername, xpwd);

        if (match == true)
        {
            Session["Username"] = xusername;
            Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Invalid UserName or Password');", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        Label1.Text = ee.Message.ToString();

    }
    finally
    {
        oBAL = null;
    }

}
```

BusinessLayer

```
public bool checking(string susername, string spwd)
 {
     ownerDAL oDAL = new ownerDAL();
    bool match = false;


    DataSet ds = oDAL.Logincheck();


    try
     {
         int noofrows = ds.Tables["Userstable"].Rows.Count;
         for (int i = 0; i < noofrows; i++)
         {
             if ((ds.Tables["Userstable"].Rows[i]["username"].ToString() == susername) && (ds.Tables["Userstable"].Rows[i]["pwd"].ToString() == spwd))
             {
                 match = true;
             }
         }
         return match;


     }
     catch
     {
         throw;
     }
     finally
     {
         oDAL = null;
     }
  }
  }
```

DataLayer

```
       public DataSet Logincheck()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("login", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    try
    {

        da.Fill(ds, "Userstable");
        return ds;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

}
```

StoredProcedure

```
                ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.login

(
@iusername  varchar(50),
@ipwd varchar(50)


)

 AS
   BEGIN


 SELECT     username, pwd
   FROM         register
   WHERE     (username = @iusername) AND (pwd = @ipwd)
```

END

Table name :register
 Fields:
username(primarykey)
pwd

I think it is a simple mistake .But as a beginner i cannot locate it.Please suggest a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the match at the Busines layer 
so you need a DataSet with complete userlist 
so change the procedue like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.login    

 AS
   BEGIN    

 SELECT     username, pwd
   FROM         register
```

Or you can pass the parameters to procedure (From  DataLayer) like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(UserName);
cmd.Parameters.Add(Password);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I did as your suggestion.But still it shows the error as "Procedure or function 'login' expects parameter '@iusername', which was not supplied."

Comment: which one you modified - change the procedure or pass the parameter?

Comment: I changed the procedure.On giving breakpoint it goes to the try of the dll and  try
    {

        da.Fill(ds, "Userstable");
        return ds;
    } execute the line da.Fill(ds,"usertable");and then exit from the try.Doesn't return

Comment: you are taking one a single table so use DataTable insted of Dataset and check that the datatable(that you return from datalayer) contains the whole username and password that get from the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure accepts two parameters username and password but you are not supplying it.
Change your DAL function `Logincheck()` to accept two parameters just like you did it in your `bool checking(string susername, string spwd)` in Business layer.

Then Modify the `Logincheck()` to pass parameters to StoredProcedure..
And you dont need that additional check again(Username and password) on BAL as you are already doing it in your SP.your `Logincheck()` in DAL can very well return true/false based on the credentials

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure requires two parameters to verify login and you are not supplying it. Either pass the username and password to your Sp or change your to the following it will work as you are checking username and password in bl.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.login
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT     username, pwd    FROM         register
    WHERE     (username = @iusername) AND (pwd = @ipwd)
  end
```